# Lags don't like Trend

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, plm

Let's take data

```
library(plm)
library(dplyr)
data("EmplUK", package="plm")
dep_var<-EmplUK['capital']
df1<-EmplUK[-6]
df1<-df1[-c(1:5),]
head(df1)
   firm year sector    emp    wage   output
6     1 1982      7  3.166 14.8681  98.6151
7     1 1983      7  2.936 13.7784 100.0301
8     2 1977      7 71.319 14.7909  95.7072
9     2 1978      7 70.643 14.1036  97.3569
10    2 1979      7 70.918 14.9534  99.6083
11    2 1980      7 72.031 15.4910 100.5501
```

I want to write a function which will take lag to third variable (column) and trend with respect to years. After that I want to perform panel random individual effects regression.

**My work so far**

```
fit_panel_lr <- function(y, x) {
  x <- x %>%
    group_by_at(1) %>%
    mutate(across(colnames(x)[3], dplyr::lag, n = 2, default = NA))

  x[, length(x) + 1] <- y
  x <- na.omit(x)

  x <- cbind(x, "Trend" = as.numeric(as.factor(x[, 2])))


  varnames <- names(x)[3:(length(x))]
  varnames <- varnames[!(varnames == names(y))]
  form     <- paste0(varnames, collapse = "+")
  x_copy   <- data.frame(x)
  model    <- plm(as.formula(paste0(names(y), "~", form)), data = x_copy,
                  model = "random", effect = "individual")
}
```

But now when I'm trying to perform my regression :

```
fit_panel_lr(dep_var, df1)
```

I see error :

> Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models,
> random.dfcor,  :    0 (non-NA) cases

However if I delete from my function lag feature, everything is working.

It's very likely that the problem is in fact that when I'm taking lag 2, I completely omit firm 1.

Comment: The logic of "lag 2" when you only have two rows is something you need to figure out first. One idea is to `group_by_at(1) %>% filter(n() > 2)`, which will remove firm 1 and should avoid the error. Your problem is not that you omit firm 1, but that firm 1 data is all `NA` because you've lagged outside of its size. (You may need more than 2 observations/rows, since it may be difficult to regress on a single observation; depending on the number of dependent variables, perhaps `n() > 4` or more. Again, it depends.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You're right. Do you know maybe how can I obtain indexes, which rows were deleted by filter function ? Intuitively something like 'which.deleted.by(filter(n()>2)'

Comment: Not natively to dplyr or R, you need to bake that in to your process. For instance, if you have a unique id field, then you can use `anti_join` on `x` (original) and your new dataframe to find the rows that are missing. Or you can filter a second time with `%>% group_by_at(1) %>% filter(n() <= 2)` (or whatever you change `2` to) to get the missing rows. BTW, `x_copy` is confusing me; since R operates with copy-on-write, and you do not reference the original `x` again, why do you need to copy it? You're protecting nothing and doubling your memory usage (if that's a concern).

Comment: Why don't you use plm's lag function?